# unable to access INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION despite having the recommend iAM config

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an issue accessing BigQuery INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION (link [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs-by-organization))

I am trying to gauge the BigQuery spending by users by jobs. I am able to access INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER but unable to access INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_FOLDER and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION.

I already have the BigQuery Resource Admin and BigQuery Resource Viewer roles as recommended from [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs-by-organization#required_role)

Comment: As per the documentation you should have BigQuery Resource Viewer IAM role on your organization, not at  project level.